# File dates copied with "cp -p" are set to "now"

Tags: linux, macos, sd-card, cp, exfat

I'm using my Mac to try to copy the content of a smartphone's SD card to a larger card. Because I don't want all the pictures to get new creation dates I used the `--preserve` option like this:
`cp -pr /Volumes/OldSD/ /Volumes/NewSD`

The file system on both the old and new cards is ExFAT and it does not show me any file owner other than my own user.

I end up with all file dates (created, last modified) being set to 'now'.

Using the `-a` option didn't help either.

What's going wrong?

---

One more observation: It only happens when copying from that SD card. When I use `cp -p` with files on my Mac it preserves all dates correctly.

Answer (score 0):

After some wasted effort below…

**Use  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>C</kbd>  and  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>V</kbd>** .
It just works.

---

Seems like you're trying to use linux syntax on Mac. They are not identical.

macOS cp man - https://ss64.com/osx/cp.html

linux cp man - https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html

I'd guess you need `cp -Rp /Volumes/OldSD/ /Volumes/NewSD`

*hmmm… nope. This doesn't work either.*
*Testing, this preserves the modified date, but sets the created date to the same value as the modified date.*
[image]

Further research shows this seems to be a known issue… [How to keep original "date created" when copying via Terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/199536/how-to-keep-original-date-created-when-copying-via-terminal/199574#199574)

ExFAT, btw cannot hold unix [or Mac] permissions or ACLs, so it's unlikely any other data than dates/owners would survive the copy.

Comment: Any idea what's going on, or why it doesn't work as expected?

Comment: All the info I have is in the linked question.